# Having issue on loading elements to each container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to not load more than 9 `alert` on each `.content`  but in result I am packing every number in group of 9 items and eliminating any items less than 10!

For example if the random value is 8 then nothing will shows in the content or if the random number is 19 only two set of content displays

How can I fix the following demo?

```js
var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
console.log(itemsNumber);
var contents = $('.contents');
var element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++, j++) {      
  element.append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + i + '</div>');
  if (j == 9) {
    contents.append(element);
    element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
    j = -1;
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but from 0 to 9 it's ***10 items***. Not 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you condition to append the content is based on `j == 9`, so if you have less than 9 items it will never be true and never append. You can add `|| i === itemsNumber - 1` to tell if you are at the end of all the items.

```js
var itemsNumber = 8; //Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
console.log(itemsNumber);
var contents = $('.contents');
var element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++, j++) {      
  element.append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + i + '</div>');
  if (j === 9 || i === itemsNumber - 1) {
    contents.append(element);
    element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
    j = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition `i % 9 == 8` as break point

```js
var itemsNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
console.log(itemsNumber);
var contents = $('.contents');
var element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
for (var i = 0; i < itemsNumber; i++) {      
  element.append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Alert ' + i + '</div>');
  if (i % 9 == 8) {// break point
    contents.append(element);
    element = $('<div class="content"></div>');
  }else if(i == itemsNumber - 1){// last loop
    contents.append(element);
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents text-center">

</div>
```